# Selenium sendKey() not working with new Chrome version

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

my java application using selenium was working yesterday, and this morning my chrome version updated to Version 53.0.2785.116 m. It still works in IE/Firefox. The line that is not executing properly is just sending a tab:

```
curElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

I have tried catching any exceptions thrown by this line, but non fire. It just fails silently. My application relies on it being able to move through the fields. This is mostly just to call attention to the issue and hopefully find a solution. Api guide to selenium if that helps anyone.
 https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html

Took a look at the Chrome release notes, and did not see anything that pertained exactly to this issue. https://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/

Comment: Try using the latest [ChromeDriver 2.24](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/)

Comment: Thank you for the link! I had not found a new version. It worked.